# Restructuring table elements on minimizing to mobile size using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with 5 columns(viz. col1, col2..., col5). When I minimize it the a mobile size, i want the columns 3 to 5 to be shown as a row, which I am achieving via:

```
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "col3"; }
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "col4"; }
td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "col5"; }
```

I want to show the col1 and col2 as a column. So the required design would be:

```
        |           |   COL3 
COL1    |   COL2    |   COL4
        |           |   COL5
```

I am not understanding how to do it in using bootstrap css. Any help is deeply appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">col1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">col2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">col3</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">col4</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">col5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/RcDM1pRUp1)